# Using Rmagick to resize height first

Tags: rmagick

I am trying to resize an image with Rmagick and if I use the `resize_to_fit` method to always resize the height first, preferring that to width, but it seems as if most of my images are being resized to width first. IS there anyway using the `resize_to_fit` method to tell it "prefer height over width"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts and some code.

What differences do you see? How can you tell it's width first? I don't see a case where the end result should be a different size, if it's a quality problem an example might help.

It doesn't look like the api exposes a way to stretch one way and then another but we can certainly make a method or two to give it a try. There are two approaches below, the first, **two_step_resize** resizes in one direction and the the other. The second, **resize_with_rotate** rotates the image, resizes it, and then rotates it back.

For the examples I ran it through I don't see any oddness in either solution.

```
require 'RMagick'


#Change the size in two steps, height first then width
def two_step_resize(img, filename, max_x, max_y)
  x = img.columns
  y = img.rows

  #make sure it's a float w/ the 1.0*
  ratio = (1.0*x)/y  

  new_y = max_y
  new_x = ratio * new_y

  if (new_x > max_x)
    new_x = max_x
    new_y = new_x / ratio
  end

  # do the change in two steps, first the height
  img.resize!(x, new_y);
  #then the width
  img.resize!(new_x, new_y)

  #save it, with the least compression to get a better image
  res.write(filename){self.quality=100}

end

#spin the image before resizing
def resize_with_rotate(img, output_filename, max_x, max_y)
  res = img.rotate(90).resize_to_fit(max_y, max_x).rotate(-90)
  res.write(output_filename){self.quality=100}
end

img = Magick::Image.read(filename).first
two_step_resize(img, "2-step.jpg", 100, 200)

img = Magick::Image.read(filename).first
resize_with_rotate(img, "rotate.jpg", 100, 200)
```

Comment: actually, the best solution I found was to use resize_to_fill! to crop the image down to get the dimensions I wanted. I didn't understand that it doens't matter what the width or the height is, whichever was bigger would be the num I scaled to, since it would keep the aspect ratio. I will give you the points for being the one to answer, though.

Answer (score 12):

I don't understand what you mean by *to resize height first*. So perhaps I'm wrong with my answer.

When you resize you have three possibilities: You may keep the ratio (`resize_to_fit`) or crop the picture (`resize_to_fill`) or stretch/shrink the picture (`scale`?)

With `resize_to_fit` you can define a maximum width and optional a maximum length (default is the given width).

Example: `img.resize_to_fit(300)`. Depending on your picture you get a picture with maximum width 300 or length 300. The other dimension is calculated by the ratio. A 50x100 picture becomes 150x300. A 100x50 picture becomes 300x150.

If you want a 300x400 picture you can't use `img.resize_to_fit(300,400)`, it would check, which dimension does fit first and calculate the other dimension depending on it.

If your *prefer height over width* means, that you want a given height (e.g. 300) and the width should be calculated by the picture ratio, you may use `resize_to_fit(1000000, 300)`.
Every times the height 300 will be reached before the width 1000000 is reached, your picture will get the height 300.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the height max value and let Rmagick calculate the corresponding width by using the **change_geometry** method.

This can be useful in case you want to set the max height of a landscape image and do not want to specify the corresponding width to preserve the ratio:

```rb
require "rmagick"
include Magick

img = ImageList.new("<path_to_your_img>") # assuming a landscape oriented img
img.change_geometry("x395") do |cols, rows, img| # set the max height 
  img.resize(cols, rows)
end
```

Do remember you always have to pass a block to the change geometry method.
You can find more information on the official [documentation](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#change_geometry).

Cheers